# No se genera nuevo proyecto en Ionic

Tags: android, nodejs, ionic, cordova

Instale NodeJS, con su respectivo cordova y ionic todo bien hasta aquí, mi problema reside en cuando intento crear un nuevo proyecto tecleo en consola

```
ionic start Holamundo tabs
```

y ejecutó primero me dice que el directorio no se encontró a lo que cree el directorio manual vuelvo a ejecutar y me dice que encontró el directorio que si deseo escribir le digo que s y como que empieza a hacer algo pero de hay no pasa se queda no manda error de nada. Alguien conoce la solución...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el error realmente?

Comment: se queda hay en preparing directory .\myApp no descarga nada no manda ningun error absolutamente nada y la carpeta queda vacía no agrega ningún archivo